# Kafka Consumers subscribed to different topics in same consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer, kafka-topic

I am starting with kafka , have a question on the consumer groups. We have an application where we want different consumers from same group subscribing to different topics. The grouping is done based on some business criteria .  To be specific consumer 1 from group A and consumer 2 from group A are subscribed to Topic 1 and Topic 2  each with 10 partitions. Does this mean that there consumer 1 can scale to 10 and consumer 2 also can scale to 10 since they are subscribed to different topics. Is this a correct design

Comment: it depends on how your code is, need to look at code how you are spinning consumers

Answer (score 1):

yes, since within a topic kafka try to assign partitions to consumers as equal as possible. The key is `topic:consumer_group_id` so it doesn't matter `another_topic:same_consumer_group_id` - it's another key, and consumer with `topic:consumer_group_id` could be scaled to partitions number